# Modeling relationship between one variable and maximum values of another variable

Tags: modeling, extreme-value

I'm having trouble with this because I suspect I'm missing some key terminology in how to ask this question. I have data that shows a relationship shown below:

[image]

Notice how as js_avg increases, the maximum s for a given js_avg seems to decrease? For reference, these are data from bedrock streams, where we measured average bedrock joint spacing (the number of joints in the bedrock per unit distance, js_avg) and the slope of the stream (s). These data were collected using systematic random sampling from a population of bedrock river sites.

I can do basic stats like a regression model (or multiple regression, since I have a bunch of variables that relate to s in this way), or spearman correlations, and get somewhat significant results, but what I'd really like to do is have a way of robustly showing that s is limited as js_avg increases (i.e., the maximum possible value of s decreases as js_avg increases), which is what I interpret from this plot (with the exception of a single outlier).

Can anyone suggest a statistical tool for describing the relationship in these data? This is particularly tricky because I doubt this data describe the actual maximum value of s for a given js_avg (i.e., there is likely variability about some idealized maximum, and I'd like to quantify that).

Comment: There is a great deal that can be said.  For starters, you might consider plotting the product of `s` and `js_avg` against `js_avg`.  Along those lines--is there any theory to suggest a functional relationship between these two variables?

Comment: I tried plotting the product vs the independent variable, as you suggest. I found a significant positive correlation (spearman cor test), but I'm unsure how to interpret those data. Any references or suggestions on readings to understand that method more?

theory: yes, the idea is that as bedrock becomes more broken up (more joints per unit length, higher js_avg), the slope of a river should decrease, since the river needs less power to erode that more broken bedrock (lower slope yields less erosive power). There should be a negative relationship between these variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite old, but to wrap things up: I ended up solving this problem using quantile regression, using the [quantreg package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantreg/index.html). I found it suitable to model the 0.90 quantile, which stood in for a rough upper bound on the data.